# Python+ Jenkins

Tags: python, csv, jenkins

Друзья, не могу разобраться в работе `csv`. Каким образом идет запись? У меня есть набор данных - имя  + значение. При печати `print(test)` всё отображается правильно.

Уже почитал документацию, и другие сайты, но не могу понять, что не так?! Спасайте!

```
import jenkins
import csv
server_url = 'httP://url' 
server = jenkins.Jenkins(server_url, None, None)
test = server.get_all_jobs(folder_depth=None)
print(test)

with open ('new1.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    a = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=':')
    a.writerows(test)
```

print(test) выдает следующее:

> [{'class': 'hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet', 'url': 'URL1', 'fullname': 'Name1', 'color': 'red', 'name': 'Name1'}, {' class': 'hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet', 'url': 'URL2', 'fullname': 'Name2', 'color': 'red', 'name': 'Name2'}, {'_clas s': 'hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet', 'url': 'URL3', 'fullname': 'Name3', 'color': 'red', 'name': 'Name3'} ...

а new1.csv выдает

> url:fullname:color:name url:fullname:color:name url:fullname:color:name ...

Comment: я как понимаю test это список словарей? Если так то, writerows ожидает получить список списков, поэтому он преобразует каждый словарь в список. В python преобразование словаря в список приводит к получению списка ключей, которые как я понимаю записываются в файл.

Comment: А в каком формате вы предполагаете увидеть выход csv?

Comment: Идеально ( понятно, не факт. что реализуемо) было бы видеть информацию следующий образом столбцами:
URL  color  name fullname /n
url1   color1 name1 name1 /n
url2   color2 name2 name2 /n
....

Comment: Попробуйте использовать DictWriter
`a = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('url', 'color', 'name', 'fullname'), extrasaction='ignore', delimiter=" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не обязательно использовать инструменты библиотеки `csv`, подстраивая свои данные под требуемый формат, можно воспользоваться простым вариантом.

```
s = [{'class': type, 'url': 'url1', 'fullname': 'name1', 'color': 'red', 'name': 'name1'}, 
     {'class': int, 'url': 'url2', 'fullname': 'name2', 'color': 'blue', 'name': 'name2'}]

delim = ':'
shape = 'url', 'color', 'name', 'fullname'

with open('new.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(delim.join(shape))
    for _dict in s:
        f.write('\n')
        for n, key in enumerate(shape):
            f.write('{}{}'.format(delim * bool(n), _dict[key]))
```

Comment: Ругается вот на что:
List indices must be  integers or slices, not str

Ругается на строку 
 f.write('{}{}'.format(delim * bool(n), _dict[key]))

Comment: Проверьте, какой тип у `_dict`? В вашем примере был список словарей - я его обозначил `s`. Соответственно, тип `_dict` должен быть словарем.

Comment: да, переменная `_dict` у меня действительно типа dict. В чем может быть сейчас проблема?

Comment: разобрался. @mkkik спасибо